# Text below the bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a website with a carousel on the top and all other content below the carousel, but anything which I am writing below the carouse apperars behind the carousel not below it. How do I solve this? (check the attached code for more info)
I only want to keep the navigation menu and heading over the carousel, rest all other things below it(check the attached link of screenshot).

```css
.carousel-div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="carousel-div">
  <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel_id" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="carousel_id" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="carousel_id" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="carousel_id" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="carousel_id" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="carousel_id" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      <li data-target="carousel_id" data-slide-to="5"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1800/600" class="d-block img-fluid img1">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1800/600?gravity=east" class="d-block img-fluid img1">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1800/600?gravity=west" class="d-block img-fluid img1">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1800/600?gravity=north" class="d-block img-fluid img1">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1800/600?gravity=south" class="d-block img-fluid img1">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1800/600?gravity=east" class="d-block img-fluid img1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel_id" data-slide="prev">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel_id" data-slide="next">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<p>I need to write this content below the carousel</p>
```

[Check this screenshot for more info.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH4V2.jpg)

Comment: All you need to do is remove [`position:fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed) from `.carousel-div`.

Comment: Would something like **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58175194/4512005)** do?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need this code?

```
.carousel-div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Why not just do this (you have not given any reason why you want the carousel fixed):

```js
// Match navbar text colors with slides
// as you need using data-navbar-text="dark"
// or data-navbar-text="light"
$('#carousel_id').on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
  var $navBar = $('#mainNav');
  var currSlide = $(this).find('.carousel-item.active');
  var textClass = currSlide.data('navbar-text');
  $navBar.removeClass('dark');
  $navBar.removeClass('light');
  $navBar.addClass(textClass);
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed !important;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.carousel-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#mainNav a {
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: color 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: color 200ms linear;
  transition: color 200ms linear;
}

#mainNav.dark a {
  color: #111;
}

#mainNav.light a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm dark" id="mainNav">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <svg class="d-block" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 612 612" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" focusable="false"><title>Bootstrap</title><path fill="currentColor" d="M510 8a94.3 94.3 0 0 1 94 94v408a94.3 94.3 0 0 1-94 94H102a94.3 94.3 0 0 1-94-94V102a94.3 94.3 0 0 1 94-94h408m0-8H102C45.9 0 0 45.9 0 102v408c0 56.1 45.9 102 102 102h408c56.1 0 102-45.9 102-102V102C612 45.9 566.1 0 510 0z"></path><path fill="currentColor" d="M196.77 471.5V154.43h124.15c54.27 0 91 31.64 91 79.1 0 33-24.17 63.72-54.71 69.21v1.76c43.07 5.49 70.75 35.82 70.75 78 0 55.81-40 89-107.45 89zm39.55-180.4h63.28c46.8 0 72.29-18.68 72.29-53 0-31.42-21.53-48.78-60-48.78h-75.57zm78.22 145.46c47.68 0 72.73-19.34 72.73-56s-25.93-55.37-76.46-55.37h-74.49v111.4z"></path></svg>
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div id="navb" class="navbar-collapse collapse hide">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="carousel-div mb-5">
  <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel_id" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="carousel_id" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="carousel_id" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="carousel_id" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="carousel_id" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="carousel_id" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active" data-navbar-text="dark">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1800/600" class="d-block">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" data-navbar-text="light">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1800/600?gravity=east">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" data-navbar-text="dark">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1800/600?gravity=west">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" data-navbar-text="light">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1800/600?gravity=north">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item" data-navbar-text="dark">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1800/600?gravity=south">
      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel_id" data-slide="prev">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel_id" data-slide="next">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2>I need to write this content below the carousel</h2>
  <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>

  <p>The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>

  <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.</p>

  <p>Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

  <p>First divide grass beast grass, shall. Which. You a fowl he won't after subdue days Over under whose form female. Subdue given greater lights, unto.</p>

  <p>May. Fruit us winged firmament. For divide dominion divided. Place image waters cattle very appear whales void moved gathered fourth have waters appear you're fruit herb yielding waters fish. Second she'd said abundantly seas.</p>

  <p>You first signs god living make to she'd fruitful him beginning male fish which all waters don't you'll, you likeness subdue subdue whales fifth which saying seasons there very have rule give. The bearing. Divide saw bearing. And saying a for.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: I have to keep the navigation menu on top of the carousel, that's why carousel is fixed.

Comment: @Rishabh Then make the *navigation* fixed, not the carousel. I have edited my answer, please check it out.

Answer (score -1):

```
.carousel-div {
position:initial;
width:100%;
}
```

Change the css of `.caraousel-div` from `position:fixed` to `position:initial`. (you do not have to use initial only, you can use various values depending upon your requirement, but fixed is not the one you want to use if you want to use rest of the page for other purposes too)

`position:fixed`, does not leave any space (hence, you are not able to place any text anywhere else on the page) on the page of the element.

Refer https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp.